# WebGL - Rendering to framebuffer instead of to canvas example extended

Tags: webgl, textures, framebuffer, render-to-texture

### The Goal

I am trying to extend the [WebGL Render to Texture Tutorial](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-render-to-texture.html) to learn WebGL better. So far, I've been able to adjust it so that it renders an image textured-cube instead:

[image]

Now, what I'm trying to do is I would like to add a blur filter using a [two-pass blur](https://lisyarus.github.io/blog/graphics/2022/04/21/compute-blur.html) so essentially the steps I want to do (rephrased from the two-pass blur blog post):

1 - Render texture to framebuffer1 (lines 300-312 in the code below)

2 - Render scene with horizontal blur to framebuffer2 (lines 319-332 in the code below)

3 - Render scene with vertical blur to canvas (commented out 337-353 in the code below)

---

### What I've Tried

I have this working if I combine steps 2&3 into one double-nested for-loop. The problem is that the runtime for that is O(N^2), so I'm trying to split into two passes. Here's how I do it.

I'm copying the same code from the [WebGL basics tutorial](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-render-to-texture.html) and just changing the following:

- Create a second `framebuffer`, `fb2`, with a new `targetTexture2` attached to it at `gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`
- Set size of `targetTexture2` with a size of `vec2(gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height)`.
- In the second block of code where we render to the canvas by *unbinding `fb`*, I instead bind `fb2` and render to that
- I then set a uniform float called `isHorizontal` that is passed to the fragment shader to `isHorizontal = 0.0`. (this part does nothing in the code now, but will be used for the blur passes later)
- Then I run the same code as in the tutorial to render to canvas but I bind `targetTexture2` instead, now that we just rendered to it.

---

### The Problem

The problem is that for some reason, the `targetTexture2`, the one that is supposed to contain the cube scene, is empty. I have a debug line (line 62) in the code commented out in the fragment shader that is supposed to color a pixel `green` if the `targetTexture2` sample has a value, `red` otherwise.

It always shows red :(

The code right now works and displays a rotating cube with leaves texture. But if you:

- Change line 320 to `gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb2);` (render first pass to fb2)
- Uncomment lines 337-354 (use first pass' color attachment to as input texture for second pass)

then it breaks. Using the debug line, you'll see it's now all red. I'm expecting something like the image above if I'm running the normal code. Or something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3tSd.png) using the debug line.

I'm so confused... This isn't even the hard part, I haven't done the blurring yet.

---

Here is the code. Just add it all to a single directory, make sure the names are: `index.html`, `style.css`, `leaves.jpg`:

#### The Image File:

Can be any jpg, but I'm using [this picture](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/leaves.jpg).

#### HTML File:

```
<!-- Licensed under a BSD license. See license.html for license -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
<link type="text/css" href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="description">
Render To Texture<br/>
</div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="vertex-shader-3d" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;

uniform mat4 u_matrix;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  // Multiply the position by the matrix.
  gl_Position = u_matrix * a_position;

  // Pass the texcoord to the fragment shader.
  v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="fragment-shader-3d" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

// Passed in from the vertex shader.
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

uniform float u_isKernel;
uniform float u_isHorizontal;
uniform vec2 u_textureSize;

// The texture.
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {        
        vec4 color_sample = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
        
        // isColor       = is colored before blur
        float isColor = length(color_sample) > 0.0 ? 1.0 : 0.0;
        
        gl_FragColor = color_sample;
        // The commented out is intended for debugging
        // It is supposed to render out a texture as is, if "isHorizontal" is == 1.0
        // Else it's supposed to render red if the texture has no value
        //                              green if the texture has a value
        // In a perfect world, I should see the cube but in stenciled out green color, but I see all red, indicating
        // the texture being passed is empty
        //gl_FragColor = (u_isHorizontal * isColor) * color_sample + (1.0-u_isHorizontal) * (1.0-isColor) * vec4(1,0,0,1) + (1.0-u_isHorizontal) * (isColor) * vec4(0,1,0,1); 
}
</script>
<!--
for most samples webgl-utils only provides shader compiling/linking and
canvas resizing because why clutter the examples with code that's the same in every sample.
See https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-boilerplate.html
and https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html
for webgl-utils, m3, m4, and webgl-lessons-ui.
-->
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/m4.js"></script>
<script>
"use strict";

function main2(image) {
  // Get A WebGL context
  /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
  var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  // setup GLSL program
  var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["vertex-shader-3d", "fragment-shader-3d"]);

  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
  var texcoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texcoord");

  // lookup uniforms
  var matrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_matrix");
  var textureLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_texture");
  var textureSizeLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_textureSize");
  var isKernelLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_isKernel");
  var isHorizontalLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_isHorizontal");
    
  var isHorizontal = 1.0;
  // Create a buffer for positions
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  // Put the positions in the buffer
  setGeometry(gl);

  // provide texture coordinates for the rectangle.
  var texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
  // Set Texcoords.
  setTexcoords(gl);


  /** 
  
  Create a texture.
  
  **/
  var texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  // Set the parameters so we can render any size image.
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

  // Upload the image into the texture.
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
  
    
  /** 
  
  Create a texture to render to FIRST, this renders a scene normally
  
  **/
  const targetTextureWidth = 1024.0;
  const targetTextureHeight = 1024.0;
  const targetTexture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture);

  {
    // define size and format of level 0
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA,
                  targetTextureWidth, targetTextureHeight, 0,
                  gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

    // set the filtering so we don't need mips
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  }
    
  // Create and bind the framebuffer
  const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

  // attach the texture as the first color attachment
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture, 0);
    
     
  /**
  
  Create a texture to render to SECOND
  
  **/
  // We need two fb's: first to render the texture to, plain and easy
  // Second to render the transformed scene to. Why can't I reuse the same fb? I have no clue
  // This is the second
  const targetTexture2 = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture2);

  {
    // define size and format of level 0
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA,
                  gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height, 0,
                  gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

    // set the filtering so we don't need mips
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  }
    
  const fb2 = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb2);
    
  // attach the texture as the first color attachment
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture2, 0);

    
    
    
  function degToRad(d) {
    return d * Math.PI / 180;
  }

  var fieldOfViewRadians = degToRad(60);
  var modelXRotationRadians = degToRad(0);
  var modelYRotationRadians = degToRad(0);

  // Get the starting time.
  var then = 0;

  requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);

  function drawCube(aspect, transform) {
    // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
    gl.useProgram(program);

    // Turn on the position attribute
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);

    // Bind the position buffer.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

    // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
    var size = 3;          // 3 components per iteration
    var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
    var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
    var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
    var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
        positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

    // Turn on the texcoord attribute
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);

    // bind the texcoord buffer.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);

    // Tell the texcoord attribute how to get data out of texcoordBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
    var size = 2;          // 2 components per iteration
    var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
    var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
    var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
    var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(texcoordLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

    // Compute the projection matrix
    var projectionMatrix = m4.perspective(fieldOfViewRadians, aspect, 1, 2000);
    var cameraPosition = [0, 0, 2];
    var up = [0, 1, 0];
    var target = [0, 0, 0];

    // Compute the camera's matrix using look at.
    var cameraMatrix = m4.lookAt(cameraPosition, target, up);

    // Make a view matrix from the camera matrix.
    var viewMatrix = m4.inverse(cameraMatrix);

    var viewProjectionMatrix = m4.multiply(projectionMatrix, viewMatrix);
    
    if (transform) {
        var matrix = m4.xRotate(viewProjectionMatrix, modelXRotationRadians);
        matrix = m4.yRotate(matrix, modelYRotationRadians);   

        // Set the matrix.
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matrixLocation, false, matrix);
    } else {
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matrixLocation, false, viewProjectionMatrix);
    }
      
    // textureSize
    gl.uniform2f(textureSizeLocation, targetTextureWidth, targetTextureHeight);
    gl.uniform1f(isKernelLocation, transform ? 1.0 : 0.0);
    gl.uniform1f(isHorizontalLocation, isHorizontal);
      
    // Tell the shader to use texture unit 0 for u_texture
    gl.uniform1i(textureLocation, 0);

    // Draw the geometry.
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6 * 6);
  }

  // Draw the scene.
  function drawScene(time) {
    // convert to seconds
    time *= 0.001;
    isHorizontal = 1.0;
    
    // Subtract the previous time from the current time
    var deltaTime = time - then;
    // Remember the current time for the next frame.
    then = time;

    // Animate the rotation
    modelYRotationRadians += -0.7 * deltaTime;
    modelXRotationRadians += -0.4 * deltaTime;

    webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    
     
    {
      // render to our targetTexture by binding the framebuffer
      gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

      // pass in texture of picture of leaves to render the cube with
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

      // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
      gl.viewport(0, 0, targetTextureWidth, targetTextureHeight);

      // Clear the attachment(s).
//      gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);   // clear to blue
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

      const aspect = targetTextureWidth / targetTextureHeight;
      drawCube(aspect, true);
    }
    
    
    const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    {
      // render to the canvas
      gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);

      // render the cube with the texture we just rendered to
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture);
        
      // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
      gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

      // Clear the canvas AND the depth buffer.
      gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);   // clear to clear
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

      drawCube(aspect, false);
    }
      
      // TODO: 
      // Render to fb *again* and then render final scene to canvas
//    isHorizontal = 0.0; 
//    {
//      // render to the canvas
//      gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
//
//      // render the cube with the texture we just rendered to
//      gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
//      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture2);
//        
//      // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
//      gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
//
//      // Clear the canvas AND the depth buffer.
//      gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);   // clear to clear
//      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
//
//      drawCube(aspect, false);
//    }
      
    requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);
  }
}

// Fill the buffer with the values that define a cube.
function setGeometry(gl) {
  var positions = new Float32Array(
    [
    -0.5, -0.5,  -0.5,
    -0.5,  0.5,  -0.5,
     0.5, -0.5,  -0.5,
    -0.5,  0.5,  -0.5,
     0.5,  0.5,  -0.5,
     0.5, -0.5,  -0.5,

    -0.5, -0.5,   0.5,
     0.5, -0.5,   0.5,
    -0.5,  0.5,   0.5,
    -0.5,  0.5,   0.5,
     0.5, -0.5,   0.5,
     0.5,  0.5,   0.5,

    -0.5,   0.5, -0.5,
    -0.5,   0.5,  0.5,
     0.5,   0.5, -0.5,
    -0.5,   0.5,  0.5,
     0.5,   0.5,  0.5,
     0.5,   0.5, -0.5,

    -0.5,  -0.5, -0.5,
     0.5,  -0.5, -0.5,
    -0.5,  -0.5,  0.5,
    -0.5,  -0.5,  0.5,
     0.5,  -0.5, -0.5,
     0.5,  -0.5,  0.5,

    -0.5,  -0.5, -0.5,
    -0.5,  -0.5,  0.5,
    -0.5,   0.5, -0.5,
    -0.5,  -0.5,  0.5,
    -0.5,   0.5,  0.5,
    -0.5,   0.5, -0.5,

     0.5,  -0.5, -0.5,
     0.5,   0.5, -0.5,
     0.5,  -0.5,  0.5,
     0.5,  -0.5,  0.5,
     0.5,   0.5, -0.5,
     0.5,   0.5,  0.5,

    ]);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positions, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

// Fill the buffer with texture coordinates the cube.
function setTexcoords(gl) {
  gl.bufferData(
      gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
      new Float32Array(
        [
          0, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 1,
          1, 0,

          0, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 0,
          1, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 1,

          0, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 1,
          1, 0,

          0, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 0,
          1, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 1,

          0, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 1,
          1, 0,

          0, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 0,
          1, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 1,

      ]),
      gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

function main() {
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = "./leaves.jpg";  // MUST BE SAME DOMAIN!!!
  image.onload = function() {
    main2(image);
  };
}
main();
</script>
</html>
```

#### CSS File:

```
@import url("https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-tutorials.css");
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error was in the way I was setting the second texture's width/height.

Used [SpectorJS](https://spector.babylonjs.com/) to debug and found the texture size was way off